WP sites/Woocommerce stores in multiple subfolders broken after migration
I am having a real issue with some WP sites at the moment. We have a main site plus several subfolder installations of WP linked up for a franchise but all separate, not multisite (not sure why, inherited). The sites were working fine on siteground but we've recently migrated to a new server and the migration is still not working properly.
The problem is, with Woocommerce plugin, the shop refuses to display on all but the main domain site. So main site is fine, but all subfolders' shop pages bring up a 404 not found, with the main domain error message, not the subfolder site.
Had lots of problems with other pages too, but through renaming web.config file to web.config.bak on the main site, this has alleviated a lot of issues. But now on the main site, I am left with an empty .htaccess file and I feel there must be people out there running stores like this in subfolders and main domain, so if anyone can advise on how to re-correct the setup I'd be most grateful.Not sure whether issue is with each subsite installation or the main one. Example of a subsite web.config file (redacted)
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <remove name="Main Rule"/>
        <rule name="YourSubFolderRuleName" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
          <match url="*"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="WordPress: https://domain.com/subdomainname" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
          <match url="*"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

All plugins were deactivated and problem still exists, plus I've tried switching themes to standard 2021 which was the only other WP theme installed and it didn't resolve the issue.
Additionally, due to trying to find solution I deactivated and reactivated the Woocommerce plugin and the setup doesn't complete, getting errors when it asks you to enter your country, it says it can't load them and when you skip it basically gets stuck on a loading page instead of completing the store setup.
TIA

Did you migrate to a Windows IIS server?

@TonyDjukic yes it was already migrated to a windows server, then we migrated all sites together to a new host (part of a group of sites). Do you think this is the issue? Any idea how to make it work?

I have, in the past, had numerous random issues running PHP/WP on IIS servers - the error messaging and the configuration are trickier than when you run on Apache/NGINX.  It's entirely possible that there are modules and packages that you need running that aren't running.  This could very well be a server config issue rather than just a WP/WooCommerce issue.

Thanks @TonyDjukic yes this is what I'm concerned about - the migration process these server co's seem to do is just file transfer, I can't think why they don't assess fully what's on the existing server. I think I will have to hire a developer who sets up WP servers as my "fully managed" package isn't really so fully managed.
